# Problema con conexión remota a mysql en servidor con NoIP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo un servidor que tiene instalado NoIP, en el tengo instalado un sistema del cual necesito acceder a la BD desde otra máquina, ya esta todo configurado y puedo entrar al sistema por la url, el problema que tengo es que no puedo acceder a la BD remotamente, estoy haciendo una conexión de prueba:

```
mysqli_connect("dominio.ddns.net", "usuario", "password", "database");
```

Los datos son correctos, son los que utilizo en la maquina para acceder a la BD, pero me manda este error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. in C:... on line 2

¿Alguien sabe o tiene alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema?

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, es probable que tu servidor no permita los accesos remotos.

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, ya lo pude resolver, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que tu servidor no permita el acceso remoto.

Comment: Hola, lo siento. Lo entendí como una respuesta. Lo coloco en la sección de comentarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude resolver, efectivamente como decía @PabloGonzález, el problema es que el servidor no aceptaba las conexiones remotas.

Lo resolví editando el archivo /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf, solo tuve que modificar la siguiente línea de esta manera:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Según estuve leyendo 0.0.0.0 aceptará las conexiones de cualquier IP, pero se puede poner una dirección en especifico para darle acceso solo a esa IP.

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, me alegro de haberte ayudado. Un saludo.